# Changing page asset definiton

Tags: webcenter-sites

I am on Oracle WebCenter Sites 11gR1.
I have an asset page that is on the tree of a site.

The page requirements and presentation have changed, so a new definition is needed to hold the references to other assets (the original definition can not be changed since is used in other pages). The page to change its definition is linked/referenced from other assets/URLs, so it is not possible to replace it with a new page.

Is it possible to change the page definition? How can this be achieved?
When i edit the page, the definition field is only a link to the definition, but not an editable field.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the page definition of an existing page instance.

You can change the existing page definition, that is being used in your page instances.

Go to Admin Perspective > Search > Page Definition > Search by your Page Definition > Click on Edit (pencil) and make your changes (eg: add or remove attributes).

If you want to add new page attributes, you should create the page attributes before edit the page definition.